# Transport Tracker to Track buses on Google Map in MVC Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I am developing an MVC based application in which I have to track the buses on google map like Uber Cab tracking system. 
Can someone please suggest me the proper approach how can I achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty broad question. You have any details about what you're actually asking?

Comment: Have you looked at the google maps API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/)? Is there anything you're particularty stuck on?